# Recurring events attendance database design

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am trying to build a way to manage events and events attendance.

I have an `events` table which has the following relevant fields:

```
id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE
starts_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL
ends_at TIMESTAMPTZ
recurrence_days INT
recurrence_months INT
PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

With this, I am able to get single occurrence or recurring events that are happening "today" or on any arbitrary date.

Unfortunately, I am struggling with how I should handle event attendance.  I have an `events_attendance` table in which I have the `event_id` (`id` from `events` table) and `user_id`, but I am not sure how to handle recurring events.

Is there a way to design this so that I don't need to "copy" events?

Comment: You don't have an `event_id` in your `events` table so what does the `event_id` in your `events_attendance` table refer to? I guess you are capturing individual attendees rather than a count?

Comment: events_attendance has a `event_id` which is the events.id

Comment: updated the question.  thanks!

Comment: If events_attendance is tracking attendance, why not just track the literal attendance, based on a date and timestamp?  You can define and track re-occurrence based on date, month, time, etc groupings.  But the records themselves would always be unique based on the user and date timestamp.

Comment: With regards to recurring events, you need another table that models recurrences. Recurring schedules can be difficult given that you have to cover rules around calendars. When you generate `event` records from this, you include a reference back to the `recurringevent` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to avoid recording instances of recurring events. That's what databases are for.

You need one `recurringevent` table which has a single record per recurring event, containing recurrence rules. A very simple one would be as follows:

```
id
event_name
start_date
end_date
DaysBetween
RecordCreateDateTime
RecordCreatedBy
```

Note that modelling recurring events against a calendar is complicated... once per week, once per month, second Tuesday of every month.

You need another table which records "instances" of that recurring event say `events`. It has a record for every actual event, and a reference back to `recurringevent`. Creating, editing, deleting the parent `recurringevent` record generates these records automatically.

Records in this table may or may not be generated from recurring events. You might just have a one-off event in which case you have one `events` record with no parent `recurringevent`.

```
id
recurringevent_id   (null if this is a once off)
date
event_name
RecordCreateDateTime
RecordCreatedBy
```

Then you need an `eventattendance` table with one row per attending person which refers back to `events`

```
id
event_id
user_id
event_feedback
RecordCreateDateTime
RecordCreatedBy
```

Right now your `events` table is trying to be two things. It should only represent an actual "event" and should not hold recurrence information.